# Proving that something is a normal subgroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose G is a group , and N the subgroup of G that is generated by $\{x^2 | x \in G\}$. Prove that N is a normal subgroup of G, and that $[G,G] \subset N$.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of subgroup generated by a set $S$ is ste of finite product of element of $S$ and their inverse.

So, for every $n \in N$ you can write $n=x_1^2x_2^2 \dots x_n^2$ for some $x_i \in G$.

Note that for every $g,x\in G$ it is true that $gx^2g^{-1}=(gxg^{-1})^2$ so that $gx_1^2x_2^2 \dots x_n^2=(gx_1g^{-1})^2 \cdots(gx_ng^{-1})^2$ and so you have the normality.

Now it is clear that in the quotient group every element has order at most $2$ and now you can prove that such a group is abelian .This condition is equivalent to the fact that $N$ contains the commutator group.

Comment: For abelian we have to prove that $g_1g_2N = g_2g_1N$ for any $g_1,g_2 \in G$ right? How can you use the order at most 2 to do this?

Comment: It is better to look at it in the quotient group $G/N$. Let's call it $K$. Try to demonstrate that if for every $k \in K$ the order of $k$ is at most $2$ the group is abelian .

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Let $S=\{x^2\;|\; x\in G\}$. For $x^2\in S$ and $g\in G$, $gx^2g^{-1}=(gxg^{-1})^2\in S$.

Next try to prove that $G/N$ is abelian so that $[G,G]=G'\subseteq N$.